# Removing status "Done" in Firefox 5

Tags: javascript, silverlight, firefox

I'm developing a Silverlight application. When Firefox loads the page, it displays "Done" at the bottom left of the page, covering my application. This status doesn't go away, just stays there forever. If the user hovers it, it displays on the bottom right instead. Hover again and it goes back to the left. No way to get rid of it.

Is there any way, maybe with Javascript to ask Firefox not to show the status?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove it with

```
window.status = '';
```